# My computer doesnt support Unity?

Tags: unity

I was told that my PC doesnt support Unity on install of Ubuntu 11. Its

- Intel C2D T9300 2.5 GHz
- 4GB DDR2
- 320GB HDD
- NVIDIA GeForce 8600MGT

Does it support Unity, if so, how can I enable Unity. Its currently using the Ubuntu 10 theme thingy :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably only have to allow the restricted Nvidia driver, check the hardware-card icon in the top right corner.

Answer (score 2):

Check hardware requirements https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements

Answer (score 1):

The advice above is good and it may solve the problem for you. If you are still unsure about whether Unity will work for you then here is another route you might take.

Download the iso file from the Ubuntu web site for 12.04 Desktop. From there you need to use the downloaded .iso file together with a program such as 'Brasero' or 'GNOME Baker' to burn an 'image' to a disk (on Windows use Nero).
Once you have made the disk then put it into your computer's DVD drive as the computer is booting and it should boot off the disk. Don't worry, this will not cause any problems with your computer. Eventually, you'll be given the choice, on the screen, of installing Ubuntu or just trying it. Choose 'Try Ubuntu'. This will not do anything to your hard disk. You will be able to see if you can run Unity on your computer. You can try looking for 'Additional Drivers' in th emenu system and see what it says about your computer.

If you are happy that it works then remove the disk and close down. Then boot as normal and  back-up all your important files from your hard disk. Then you can install the latest version of Ubuntu, should you wish, from the disk. 12.04 is supported for 5 years. Remember that Ubuntu 11.xx are not long term support so you'll have to upgrade somehow eventually.

If you find that your computer doesn't work the way you wish with Ubuntu 12.04 you could try installing Xubuntu 12.04 which is a lighter desktop. That has a nice panel at the bottom of the screen. If you prefer something else, to the panel, then you can install the 'Avant Windows Navigator', Cairo Dock, 'GNOME Do' or other docks which are alternatives to Unity.

Hope this helps!